# How Do I stop my Python Logger from duplicating Logs

Tags: python, logging, automated-tests

So I've written my own custom logger with formatters for the different levels.The output .txt shows the info correctly formatted, but every statement is duplicated.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import logging

# Change the current working directory
os.chdir('C:\Git_Repo\pyautotest\AutoTest\OutputLogs')


def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S - {fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

#Records Current date & time and appends it to the file name of the txt log created at the end of this script.

# Logging Levels

# DEBUG: Detailed information, typically of interest only when diagnosing problems.

# INFO: Confirmation that things are working as expected.

# WARNING: An indication that something unexpected happened, or indicative of some problem in the near future (e.g. ‘disk space low’). The software is still working as expected.

# ERROR: Due to a more serious problem, the software has not been able to perform some function.

# CRITICAL: A serious error, indicating that the program itself may be unable to continue running.



PrintLog = logging.getLogger(__name__)
PrintLog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    debug_fmt  = "%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s: %(pathname)s: Line %(lineno)s:  %(message)s"
    info_fmt = "%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    error_fmt = "%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s: %(pathname)s: Line %(lineno)s:  ERROR - %(message)s"
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(fmt="%(levelno)d: %(msg)s", datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M', style='%')  
    
    def format(self, record):

        # Save the original format configured by the user
        # when the logger formatter was instantiated
        format_orig = self._style._fmt

        # Replace the original format with one customized by logging level
        if record.levelno == logging.DEBUG:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.debug_fmt

        elif record.levelno == logging.INFO:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.info_fmt

        elif record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            self._style._fmt = MyFormatter.error_fmt

        # Call the original formatter class to do the grunt work
        result = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)

        # Restore the original format configured by the user
        self._style._fmt = format_orig

        return result

fmt = MyFormatter()
PrintLog.propagate = False

stream = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')


stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stream_handler.setFormatter(stream)


debug_handler = logging.FileHandler(timeStamped('Test Log.txt'))
debug_handler.setFormatter(fmt)
            
info_handler = logging.FileHandler(timeStamped('Test Log.txt'))
info_handler.setFormatter(fmt)
  
PrintLog.addHandler(debug_handler)
PrintLog.addHandler(info_handler)
PrintLog.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

When I call this module and pass it data from another script the output txt file appears as so.

```
INFO: 2023-11-20_11.07: Comencing Autotest.

INFO: 2023-11-20_11.07: Comencing Autotest.

INFO: 2023-11-20_11.07: Operating System = Windows

INFO: 2023-11-20_11.07: Operating System = Windows

DEBUG: 2023-11-20_11.07: C:\Git_Repo\pyautotest\AutoTest\Chris PyAuto Dev\new_test_menu.py: Line 48:  Quitting
DEBUG: 2023-11-20_11.07: C:\Git_Repo\pyautotest\AutoTest\Chris PyAuto Dev\new_test_menu.py: Line 48:  Quitting
```

So the log is taking the statements passed to it from the other .py file and correctly applying the formatting for the level assigned, but it posts twice for every statement.  How do I stop it from duplicating the statements?

Comment: Why do you have/add 2 handlers that write to same log file simultaneously? From the names you use, it looks like there is misunderstanding that you have to have separate handler for each level

Comment: like @buran mentioned, you're adding multiple handlers to the same file, which unsurprisingly results in duplicate lines. Also a much cleaner approach would be to define a function for setting the logging level (info, warn, debug,  etc.) and based on the logging level set in that function, change some of the logging methods to do nothing

Comment: Oh god I can't believe how dumb I was.

This is more than a little embarrassing. I can't remember at what point or why had  set that up, but it is at this point redundant code. 

Thanks for the extra pairs of eyes to scrutinize my code. Now if you'll excuse me, I'm going to shuffle off and pour myself a stronger cup of tea, as I clearly need the caffeine.